# How should I check to see a if value exists in PHP?

Tags: php, operator-keyword

There are many ways to see if a value exists using PHP. There's isset, !=false, !==false, !empty, etc. Which one will be the best (fast and accurate) one to use in the following situation?

```
if($_GET['test'])
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if (isset($_GET['test'])) {
   // use value
}`

Answer (score 0):

```
if(array_key_exists($_GET, "test"))
```

array_key_exists return true if a key exists in an array,
isset will return true if the key/variable exists and is not null.

Answer (score 0):

Isset is probably best because it checks if the url contains a "?test=". If you want to make sure it is not empty you have to check further.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with the php5 one type of get:

```
$test = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'test', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
if($test){
  //do something
}
```

Reference [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php), you can validate and sanitize with them. you can use "filter_input_array" for the full input types.

Answer (score -1):

isset function only checks for its avaliability you have to use empty function too in order to see if it is set and not empty also as:

```
if (isset($_GET['test']) && !empty($_GET['test'])) {
```